# Getting LazyInitializationException with hibernate4.1 and spring 3.1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using OpenSessionInViewFilter. It's the first filter in my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Here is part of my applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>

<bean id="userBc" class="com.tutorial.bc.auth.UserBcImpl">
    <property name="userDao">
      <ref local="userDao"/>
    </property>
  </bean>
...
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
```

My mapping in hbm file-

```
<set name="userCoachingRoles" table="user_coaching_role" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
      <key column="user_id"/>
      <many-to-many column="coaching_id" class="com.tutorial.entity.coaching.Coaching" lazy="proxy"/>
</set>
```

The method in my userBc where I get the user is annotated with `@Transactional` and my entity User has a method `getUserCoachingRoles`. I'm getting the exception hitting this method -

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

I'm not able to understand why there is no session even when I'm using `OpenSessionInViewFilter` . Need help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you by any chance calling `getUserCoachingRoles` in a separate thread? If so, this is expected behaviour.

As `UserCoachingRoles` isn't loaded eagerly, Spring does not have access to the database connection inside that thread and can't load it. You need to:

- create an enclosing session wrapper in your thread;
- pass the id of `UserCoachingRoles` to the thread instead of passing object and load the property inside this thread

Comment: Thanks. I was indeed calling the method in a separate thread.